# Rails: nil error class not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My code cannot find the module and returns an nil error.

```
undefined method `next' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is code

```
module Test
  class MyTestClass

    before_save :cid

    def cid
      MyTestClass.maximum(:id).next #error here, can't find MyTestClass 
    end
end
```

I tried variants like Test::MyTestClass but none worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that context, you can safely use `maximum(:id).next`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use MyTestClass inside the method 'cid'.

You can just use:

```
module Test
  class MyTestClass

    before_save :cid

    def cid
      self.maximum(:id).next
    end
  end // End of class
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyTestClass.maximum(:id).next
-> self.maximum(:id).next
```